# Timemachine - Turn off "No Backup for X Days" for secondary Disk

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, notifications

On my MacBook Air I use TimeMachine with two USB-Disks. (Latest El Capitan)

My primary disk is located at my house, the secondary at my parent's house.

As I am not always at my parents, this "No Backup for X Days" pops up daily:

[image: Backup Notification]

Does anybody know a way, how I can disable the notification for the secondary disk while leaving the notification for the primary disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the backup volume is offsite, you can simply remove it from the list in Time Machine settings whilst it's away from home. When you add it back, Time Machine will pick up the existing backup. That's what I always do myself.

As for performance, the first backup after adding the volume back has a longer preparation step (presumably for computing the diffs) but that also happens anyway after a few weeks when Time Machine stops maintaining the diffs as changes on the file system occur in real time.

Comment: Sounds cool bro!

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I just removed the disk. Will be at my parents next week and then I can try out if it resumes the backup. I'll let you know.

Comment: So I am at home now :) I just added the disk, had to unlock it manually (my backups are encrypted!), and added it back. - Yes, it took a while for the initial preparation, but then it continued where it left off. Right as you promised. Thanks for your help, it worked!